# Como faço para essa função abrir url em nova aba

Tags: php, html

O código abaixo converte `url`  texto em hiperlink:

```
$bodyText = "The text you want to filter goes here.";
function formatUrlsInText($text) {
    $reg_exUrl = "/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/";
    preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $matches);

    $usedPatterns = array();
    foreach($matches[0] as $pattern){
        if(!array_key_exists($pattern, $usedPatterns)){
            $usedPatterns[$pattern]=true;

            // now try to catch last thing in text
            $pattern2 = substr($pattern, -3);

            if($pattern2 == "gif" || $pattern2 == "peg" || $pattern2 == "jpg" || $pattern2 == "png") {
                 $text = str_replace($pattern, '', $text);
            } else {
                 $text = str_replace($pattern, ''.$pattern.'',      $text);
            }
        }
     }
     return $text;
}

$format = formatUrlsInText($bodyText);

echo $format;
```

O meu objetivo e fazer a url que ela converte abrir em nova aba. 
 Se estiver muito difícil aceitos outras funções.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [target](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) no seu link.

Insira `target='_blank'` no seu código:

`<a target="_blank" href="'.$pattern.'">'.$pattern.'</a>'`

Comment: Funciono perfeitamente, Vlw